# Gah. Your tab just crashed. How do I know what made the tab crash?

Tags: debian, firefox, bunsenlabs

I am using Firefox Quantum (57.0.1) on Bunsenlabs Hydrogen (Debian Jessie with Openbox).

For some pages, (namely, Panopticlick's result page), the tab start to load, and crash. All I then get to see is a white page with

```
Gah. Your tab just crashed.
We can help!

Choose Restore This Tab to reload the page.
```

I ve tried to open the console and reload the page, but it get cleared as soon as the tab crash, and go to `about:crashes`, but it only seems to only account for full-on firefox crash, tab crash doesn't get reported. At the very least the list was empty for me.

I sometime encounter pages that don't work properly, since I use uBlock Origin and uMatrix, so usually, when I really need a page and I can't get it to work in firefox, I just use chromium, but in this case, the whole point is to test firefox, so this workaround just don't work.

What can I do to have information on the crash? So I can then attempt to fix the problem myself, or ask for help?

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed by going to about:config, change "browser.tabs.remote.autostart=true" to "false". Do the same for "browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2" .